# Get commit message on post-commit hook and reuse it

Tags: git, githooks

Here's my post-commit file:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE

git --work-tree=../foo2 --git-dir=/m/Downloads/foo1/.git checkout -f

cd ../foo2/
git add .
git commit -m $1
```

When a commit is made on `foo1` repository, I need to move commited files to `foo2` repository and commit these files using the same commmit message.

The moving files steps is working fine. My problem now is get commit message.

Comment: why not push the commit to the other repository?

Comment: @DanielA.White you give an good idea. I can push to other local repository? I found a problem on my script: it move all files, not only the commited files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the commit message with `git show`:

```sh
git show --no-patch --format=%B
```

You can also use STDIN as the commit message when committing:

```sh
echo "foo" | git commit --file=-
```

With these two bits you should be able to get the commit message from one repo and use it as commit message in your other repo:

```sh
git --git-dir=/m/Downloads/foo1/.git show --no-patch --format=%B | git commit --file=-
```

Comment: I'm trying running this command without success: `git commit -m git show --no-patch --format=%B`

Comment: I don't understand your last example. I need to add commit message in this line: `git commit -m "COMMIT MESSAGE"`

Comment: `git show` gives you the message. You could put it in a variable and do `git commit -m "$msg"`. Instead of using a variable though, you can tell `git commit` to use the contents of standard input as the message (as shown in the second snippet). `echo "foo" | git commit --file=-` is the same as `git commit -m "foo"`.